# CSS about absolute position

Tags: html, css, styles, stylesheet

here's the example http://jsfiddle.net/FW38N/1/

how can i make the div (container) with height:auto instead of making it with fixed height

```
        .container{
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
        background-color:black;
        position:relative;
    }

    .text {
        position:absolute;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        background-color:red;
    }

<div class='container'>
        <div class='text'>

        </div></div>
```

Comment: I think this is not posible with css only, because "text" is absolute, like in "other dimension", and "container" don't know about its dimensions. Maybe to include some JavaScript to get "text" size, and apply that size (height) to "container".

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to do that without using JavaScript or jQuery.

When an element has `position:absolute`, it doesn't occupy space inside the parent. It's separate from the layout and flow of the page (like a pop-up window). In the example above, the parent will have a height of zero, because there's nothing in it taking up space. This is a fundamental part of how absolute positioning behaves.

For this reason, it's problematic to use absolute positioning for content that varies in height (except for things like pop-ups and dropdown menus, which aren't part of the main page layout anyways). In effect, every element with absolute positioning is sort of a pop-up.

If the parent had `position:absolute` instead of the child, then the parent could have `height:auto`.

Answer (score 0):

just write `height:100%;` it will set up height of div to size of text+ margins

Answer (score 0):

you could also try

```
<p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...
</p>
```

and not a div